# Create a Table that has Created Date and Update Date (Read Only)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I wonder if it is possible to create a table that has a created date and updated date every time a record is created or updated.

For example, when I insert a record into that table, the created date will auto generated in the table same with the update date.

When I modify this record, the create date won't change but the update date will change according to the date.

Many thanks

Comment: Triggers should handle it.

Comment: The most suitable option is trigger in Database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.foo
(
  ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
  CreatedDate DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  UpdatedDate DATETIME NULL
);
GO

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.foo_ForUpdate
  ON dbo.foo
  FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  UPDATE f SET UpdatedDate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    FROM dbo.foo AS f
    INNER JOIN inserted AS i
    ON f.ID = i.ID;
END
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the default value for the column to be equal to GetDate() and this will set the Created Date to the time when the record was created. This will not work for UpdatedDate because default values will be used when the record is created. For this column you can use after update trigger. Here is a link that shows how to create one :
http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2010/09/after-update-trigger-in-sql-server.html

Answer (score 2):

Trigger is a most suitable option. You can refer the sample for trigger as follows.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.TableTriggerName
ON dbo.TableName
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --
    -- Check if this is an INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE Action.
    -- Set Action to Insert by default.
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM DELETED)
    BEGIN
    END
    ELSE 
        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INSERTED) RETURN; -- Nothing updated or inserted.

    ...

    END
```

[Trigger Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx)

Comment: This shows what the skeleton of a trigger looks like, but it disregards the actual question. Where is the logic that shows how to update the value in the base table for the row(s) affected by the update?